# How to find a variable that holding a specific value

Tags: python, variables, python-3.4

If running the codes below;

```
a = 13
print (a)
```

The output will be `13` means a variable called `a` holding `13`. I'm wondering, how to display that variable ? Like;

```
a = 13
b = 13
print (13.holders) or (13.referrers) #??

>>>a,b
```

It may necessary in a script with 8K lines. Is this possible to do that? Giving a specific value and finding the variables holding it?

Comment: *"means a variable called `a` holding `13`"* - that is **not** correct, it means that the name `a` is a reference to an integer object with the value `13` (there may be other references to the same object, and reassigning the name `a` doesn't affect the underlying object beyond decrementing its reference count). Read e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do that, then you will need to have all the variables that will possibly hold 13 into one container or collection.  Array, or HashSet.  Then you can find the index, or the key of the location that holds that value.

And `locals()` is exactly that collection of all variables you created! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `locals()` and then iterating over them and checking which has this value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use garbage collector's method get_referrers for this purpose:

```
import gc

a = 123456789
b = 123456789

print gc.get_referrers(a)
```